# Lio/fabric/sdk/android/DefaultLogger;at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.<clinit>(Fabric.java:56) at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:308)

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

I am getting error while init **Fabric** with `Fabric.with(this);`.

My `build.gradle` is below:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

...

```
dependencies {
...
//twitter fabric sdk
    compile('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

My error log is as below:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/fabric/sdk/android/DefaultLogger;
>                                                                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.(Fabric.java:56)
>                                                                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:308)

Comment: Fabric comprises of many kits. Which one you trying to use? i.e crashlytics, twitter, mopub. Why not use the Fabric tool wizard to add the required code into your project?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer [Here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/twitter.html)

I just replace

```
Fabric.with(this)
```

with

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);

    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```